# How to debug python module from Python Interactive in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode to develop a python module, and triggering calls to it using the 'Python Interactive' panel (the jupyter notebook like component).

One of my module functions fails. Is there a way to place a breakpoint in the code, and get it to pause on it when triggering it from the 'Python Interactive' calls?

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled to debug my python script at first in vscode.
Create a directory `.vscode` and inside it create `launch.json` file and then from activity side bar open debug pane.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "current_working_directory_here"
        }
    ]
}
```